# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA help; IF x=TRUE then do not add and so, IF false add to the worksheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula

I have five worksheets in one workbook. In one worksheet I am trying to get a formula to reflect this logic:

In Worksheet2 if the values in column B2:B are TRUE (Y/N Boolean) then do not include them in Worksheet4, but, if B2:B is FALSE include only the data in column C2:C.

so far I was able to get only this

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('14_Day_Drop'!B2:C=TRUE, ???, ???)) No clue how to make it work.

I burned a hole in google and could not find something out there that could help with the logic. I tried COUNTIF and/or ADD I even did {"COUNT".... but it does not work.

I would really like the formula to populate all the information if FALSE from all three columns across the row. That way I don't have to do two separate formulas in the PAID worksheet.

Comment: `I am trying to get a formula to reflect this logic:` I am sorry but I find the description of the logic unclear and difficult to understand. Also, you refer to Worksheet2 and Worksheet4 but the formula refers to `14_Day_Drop`. Would you please edit you question to include sample data for Worksheet2 and an example of a successful outcome for Worksheet4 (based on the sample data). Please consider including the sample data as text tables.